# React route doesn't render my component and gives 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been practicing how to work with the latest module versions, so i'm currently trying to work with react-router-dom. It doesn't render the page component at exact path, but at the home page instead.

I tried working with other versions of react-router-dom, but still getting the same results.

```
//App.js file
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route path="/shop" component={Shop}/> 
//doesn't render at localhost://8080/shop, but at localhost://8080, it renders the Shop page
                <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            </div>
        </Router>


        )
}

export default App;

function Shop() {


        return (
            <div>
                <h3>
                    Shop
                </h3>
            </div>
        )

}
```

Its supposed to render the appropriate component, but gives 404 error..I also found out usually there's an auto-complete option(it shows 'component, components, path..' with my IDE when trying out the Route on my former versions, but here it doesn't show anything. Is it possible the Route isn't being recognized?

Answer (score 0):

try to add an 'exact' prop to your Route.

```
<Route exact path="/shop" component={Shop}/>
```

[Here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) is an explanation.

Comment: It seems to me that the trouble is not in this code, because on codesandbox this template worked, try to create-react-app one more time and reinstall dependencies. You can add this code to codesandbox so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

About is not defined anywhere. I ran your code exactly but included a function for the About page. Router was working for me. home page showed nothing, /shop had h3 tag for shop, /about had h3 tag for about.

Is the index.js calling the App? Did you make any modifications to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
    return (
     <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <div>
                <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop/>}/> 
                <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
            </div>
        </Routes>
    <BrowserRouter>
       )
}
```

- Replace component with element.
- Replace the Shop with  then About to
- Enclose all your code with the BrowserRouter in the return statement.
- This works presently with the React Router v6
- Here is the link for more info : https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/tutorial